# How to backup photos from iPhone

Tags: ios, applications, backup

What should be the proper way to backup photos from iPhone. iCloud do not have much storage for it, any apps is recommended to use for backup photos? I heard a lot of users use Google Photos for backup photos, is that reliable?

Comment: Backup to where? Your local computer? use iphoto. If you want an app that can backup your files i would look at Bittorrent sync, needs a computer to act storage though. If looking for cloud storage that are free, you get what you pay for, no guarantees. Buy a dropbox plan and use dropbox to sync your photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Photos](http://photos.google.com) lets you store unlimited photos in high quality on their servers, just by downloading the Google Photos [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-photos-free-photo-video/id962194608?mt=8). The app works great, and I've found it to be reliable. It gets 5 stars in the iOS App Store (which is really quite an achievement) and has nice extra features in the `Assistant` section, like auto-making videos from your photos/videos. Once your photos and videos are backed up to Google Photos, you can view them on phones, tablets, and computers, just by signing in to your account.

You can also spend $1 a month to purchase 50 gigabytes of iCloud storage, and turning on [iCloud Photo Library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) lets you back up all of your photos similarly (though I've found this to be slightly less reliable than Google's solution).

Read more about backing up your photos with [this New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/02/technology/personaltech/zen-and-the-art-of-managing-smartphone-photos.html?_r=0).

Comment: can i view the photos in Google Photos Apps if my phone device is offline?

Comment: @Jess Not really. Google Photos stores very compressed versions on your device and uploads the full photos to the cloud. Photos _mostly_ show up offline, but Google Photos is best with an internet connection, even a weak one. However, you can download any photo from Google Photos and save it for later in your Camera Roll.

Answer (score 0):

Three options come to mind:

- You can use iCloud to backup to iCloud Photo Library. Just go to settings, photos, and switch on iCloud Photo Library.
- If you would like to backup to iTunes, just plug in your phone, open the photos app and click "import images". This will back them up to your Mac.
- Lastly, you could just back up your iPhone. Doing a full backup would backup photos as well as everything else. This could get some complications though, for example if you wanted to restore from a different backup and wanted ONLY the photos from this backup. You can do it, but it's better to just use the photos app.

Comment: thanks. I would sync the picture to mac book using itunes as well, besides google photos.

Answer (score -1):

With the default 5 GB of iCloud storage, you can get a backup of your photos by turning on [Photo Stream](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317), and leaving Photos running on your Mac. The Mac will get new photos and videos added to your PhotoStream continuously, but your phone and iCloud storage will be limited to a max of 1000 items.

Comment: Photo Stream is not a backup solution. It makes the photos taken (or uploaded to the Photos app) in the last 30 days (limited to 1000 items as mentioned) available in all Apple devices signed in using the same Apple ID with iCloud turned on. Once a photo is older than 30 days, it is removed from all devices other than the one it is originally taken.